# How to display manufactuter on the same page in OpenCart

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart

I have many categories on my page in OpenCart. When I switch categories, products are displayed with categories on left to navigate.

Then I have a "manufacturers" category, where you can select a manufacturer from a dropdown. But, as soon as I select a manufacturer, it displays all the products of the selected manufacturer on new page, which means there's no navigation bar on the left.

Can you guys help me fix that?

Case 1: working

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDUpT.jpg

Case 2: opens in new page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsqDc.jpg

**Code**

```
<div class="list-group">
  <h3 id="znamkaLevo"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h3>

  <select onchange="gobrandpage(this.value)" class="form-control">

    <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>" 

      <?php if  ($manufacturer['manufacturer_id'] == $manufacturer_id){ 
        echo "SELECTED"; } ?> class="list-group-item active">
      <?php echo  $manufacturer['name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>

  </select>
</div>

<script>
  function gobrandpage(id){
    window.location.href=id;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `opencart` specifically, but it looks like it is either in `frames`, where you would change `window.location.href=id;` to something like `window.frames['right'].location.href=id;`, or a `div`, where you would change it to something like `window.getElementById('yourMainPage').location.href=id;`

Comment: @Sean doesn't seem to be working =\